# Notice: Undefined index: count in C://........ on line 5

Tags: php, session, variables, indexing, undefined

Probably a bit of a dumb question but I just started learning php.
I have to make some exercises and one of them is to make a php file that displays how often you have visited a page without closing your webbrowser (session variables).
I managed to do quite so, but when I open the page I get the error: Notice: Undefined index: count in ... on line 5

**PHP file:**

```
<?php
  session_start();

  $_SESSION['count']++;  


  if($_SESSION['count'] == 0){
        echo "You have not visited this page earlier yet since you closed your webbrowser";
  } else { 
        echo "You have already visited this page " . $_SESSION['count'] . " times before you closed your webbrowser";
  }

?>
```

Comment: the session array wasn't assigned a value yet.

Comment: How to solve that?

Comment: Follow the example in the manual http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php